# how to programatically open and close bottomappbar using a eventhandler that exist in a usercontrol back code?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, user-controls, appbar

I have a Windows 8 application (Xaml and C#):

I have a userControl that is included in a MainPage.

In this MainPage i have included a BottomAppBar that is fully functioning on RightClick and Windows+Z.

What i need to do is to open the BottomAppBar from an event handler (in the usercontrol back code) on an image that exists in the userControl. i need to access the BottomAppBar in order to use the property IsOpen, but i am not being able to do so. Any hint? am i missing anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am giving you simplest example, which may guide you how to do it.

### Normal Way

BlankPage4.xaml

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar IsSticky="True" IsOpen="True">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" />
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <local:MyUserControl1 />
</Grid>
```

MyUserControl1.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Button Click="btnClose_CLick" Content="Close AppBar" />
</Grid>
```

MyUserControl1.xaml.cs

```
private void btnClose_CLick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var isOpen = ((AppBar)((BlankPage4)((Grid)this.Parent).Parent).BottomAppBar).IsOpen;
    if (isOpen)
    {
        ((AppBar)((BlankPage4)((Grid)this.Parent).Parent).BottomAppBar).IsOpen = false;
    }
    else
    {
        ((AppBar)((BlankPage4)((Grid)this.Parent).Parent).BottomAppBar).IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

### MVVM Way

BlankPage4.xaml

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar IsSticky="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsOpenBottomBar}">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" />
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <local:MyUserControl1 />
</Grid>
```

MyUserControl1.xaml.cs

```
private void btnClose_CLick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var isOpen = (this.DataContext as ViewModel).IsOpenBottomBar;
    if (isOpen)
    {
        (this.DataContext as ViewModel).IsOpenBottomBar = false;
    }
    else
    {
        (this.DataContext as ViewModel).IsOpenBottomBar = true;
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _IsOpenBottomBar;
    public bool IsOpenBottomBar
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsOpenBottomBar;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsOpenBottomBar = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsOpenBottomBar");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _IsOpenBottomBar = true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Xyroid It's also worth noting that if using MVVM you probably want to avoid handlers in the xaml.cs files wherever possible (I know the OP asked specifically but). You can with MVVM also change the IsOpenBottomBar property directly in ViewModel code. For example if you only want the bar open when some image is selected, and have a property (public object ImageSelected {get; set;}) bound to said image selection - then you could avoid the click etc handler and instead simply call your IsOpenBottomBar = true|false directly from your ImageSelected code (or of course elsewhere in the VM).