# Accessing main Page UI in user Control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have mainPage.xaml and userControl.xaml.I called userControl in mainPage. mainPage has a Grid named "grd" and userControl has a button named "btn". Now when I will click on button then click event of userControl will be raised. In this event, I want to hide the Grid(that in  mainPage.xaml). How can I access mainPage controls in userControls ?

Answer (score 2):

For windows Phone 8 try this:

```
(((Application.Current as App).RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Content as Page)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access currently displayed Page using this code :

```
var mainPage = (PhoneApplicationPage)((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Content;
```

Comment: definitely, already tried this. `Application.Current..` is accessible from any control/page of your windows phone application, and returning the same result.

Comment: I am unable to use it. The code you wrote is for wp7. In wp8 I am unable to find .RootFrame.Content. Please explain

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer, in that OP wanted to set visibility of appbar, my answer will work for `Grid` also.

[how to programatically open and close bottomappbar using a eventhandler that exist in a usercontrol back code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162445/how-to-programatically-open-and-close-bottomappbar-using-a-eventhandler-that-exi/19165090#19165090)

Comment: can you please explain how it works ?
var isOpen = ((AppBar)((BlankPage4)((Grid)this.Parent).Parent).BottomAppBar).IsOpen;

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM (as you stated in your comment to @har07's answer) you should not hide the grid in the main page using an event handler in your user control page. Instead you should bind a command to the button in the control page. This command should change the view model of the main page and this change should be notified by that view model to the main page.

In the next example I use `MVVM Light` but other MVVM libraries probably work almost the same.

Add a property to the view model of your main page:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  …your code here
  private bool _isValid;
  public bool IsValid
  {
    get
    {
      return _isValid;
    }
    set
    {
      _isValid = value;
      RaisePropertyChange("IsValid");
    }
  }
}
```

In the main page bind `Visibility` to `IsValid`.

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsValid, Converter={StaticResource converter}}">
  …content here
</Grid>
```

Now, the grid is visible if IsValid is true.

Add a command to the view model of the user control:

```
public class UserControlViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  …your code here
  public RelayCommand InvalidateGridCommand { get; private set; }
  public UserControlViewModel()
  {
    InvalidateGridCommand = new RelayCommand( () => InvalidateGrid() );
  }

  private void InvalidateGrid()
  {
    var mainvm = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance(MainViewModel);
    mainvm.IsValid = false;
  }
}
```

In the user control page bind the `Button` to the `Command`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding InvalidateGridCommand}">
  Invalidate
</Button>
```

Now, clicking the button will set `IsValid` on the `MainViewModel` to false, which will, in turn, hide the `Grid`.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for an answer for this question and after some tries I could access the main page of my Windows Phone 8.1 app using:

```
var mainPage = (MainPage)(Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content.
```

To access the controls declared in the MainPage, you need also to give them a `x:Name` and change their `x:FieldModifier` to `"Internal"` or `"Public"`.